Quesion in reactjs component parameter if case
Sorry if I use the wrong term I don't know what the correct terminology. Please correct me if you could.
Let say I have a form I want to have some if case to configure it.
<Form.Select
 name="select"
 value= {isTrue?value1:value2}
 multiple = {enableMultiple}>

as you can see value can use a short form if-case to set the value
But for multiple this example will fail because I have to either have or don't have the parameter to enable/disable it, not by setting it true/false
So is there is short form for setting on/off the variable multiple in Form.Select? I am trying to doing the following
{enableMutiple ? <Form.Select value=... mutiple ...> : <Form.Select value=...>}


FYI: The short if/else you're referring to is called a ternary operator

What you do is acceptable.
Although react allows multiple to be undefined, or false.
Here
    const a = true;
    return (
      <select multiple={a}>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    );


If you really want to omit the property altogether, you can try to spread an object with properties, which could either contain the multiple property or not.
<Form.Select
  name="select"
  value= {isTrue ? value1 : value2}
  {...(enableMultiple ? {multiple: true} : {})}
>

But if your original attempt is really not working, then i would file a bug with that library.

Here, on my machine works XD
const a = true;
return (
  <select multiple={a}>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
  </select>
);

The react docs are saying that it's acceptable to pass the boolean multiple or do not pass it at all.
interface SelectHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    autoComplete?: string | undefined;
    disabled?: boolean | undefined;
    form?: string | undefined;
    multiple?: boolean | undefined;
    name?: string | undefined;
    required?: boolean | undefined;
    size?: number | undefined;
    value?: string | readonly string[] | number | undefined;
    onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<T> | undefined;
}


please post code/interfaces/etc as formatted text rather than images

using the enableMultiple && true syntax for conditional rendering of the multiple attribute in a form element is a concise and efficient way to handle such scenarios. It makes your code cleaner and easier to understand, improving readability and maintainability. This approach is a common practice in JavaScript and React development, allowing you to toggle attributes based on specific conditions without unnecessary repetition of code. Overall, it enhances the development process and helps you write more streamlined and organized code.
note:If your bets are high, it is better to use a switch case
    <Form.Select
  name="select"
  value={isTrue ? value1 : value2}
  multiple={enableMultiple && true}
>
  {/* Your select options here */}
</Form.Select>


Suspiciously ChatGPT-y.

"If your bets are high, it is better to use a switch case" What is this supposed to mean?

And you wrote a lot of text without explaining why is this actually better or even what adding && true is even supposed to do.
